# How to highlight text in a github md file

Tags: html, github, markup

I would like to highlight some text in a GitHub documentation (.md) file.

I am trying to create a `<mark>Easy Pick</mark>` label to encourage contributions in https://github.com/QasidAhmad/3gratitudes/edit/master/contributing.md as suggested here: https://seld.be/notes/encouraging-contributions-with-the-easy-pick-label

I have tried using the HTML syntax:

```
<mark> Easy Pick </mark>
```

But this does not appear to work as the preview of the file resulting from this just shows the words without any highlight.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Thank you Pang for improving the working and formatting of my question. This is the first time iv posted a question on stackoverflow so I will learn from this for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

No need to build a label button yourself. You can go to [this page on your repository](https://github.com/QasidAhmad/3gratitudes/labels) (*Issues* then *Labels*) and click *New label* to create a new label.